# @Scheduled annotation - for loop

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-scheduled

I need to use Scheduled annotation. I have couple of REST in List of String which I would like to check one by one for every 6 minutes.

1st rest should launch and after 6 mins 2nd should execute.

How to make this kind of loop inside the Scheduled method?

Moreover I can not put any arguments in method cause of error (`Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled`). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: why can't you create two methods with `@Scheduled` with 6 minutes apart

Comment: There are 11 REST which I have to check

Comment: use threads ...

Comment: @Mohammad it is impossible due to architecture

Comment: Can't you use @Scheduled with fixedDelay and keep your work-to-be-done in bean member variables? Set them up in your bean constructor.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using `SchedulingConfigurer` class instead of `@Scheduled`  and calculate the next execution time dynamically.

Here is a sample code.

```
@EnableScheduling
class SomeClass implements SchedulingConfigurer{

    // Autowire and initialize the beans you need to execute your task.

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // Execute your task
            }
        }, new Trigger() {
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                String cron = createCron(); // Create cron expression for next execution
                CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(cron);
                return trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            }
        });
    }



    private String createCron() {
      // return cron expression for next trigger
    }
}
```

This uses default scheduler available in the spring context

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I will try to execute same way you do